# Storing Circles and run efficient query using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql

In my database I have two tables where:

- Table `Pin` contains a column of type point representing lat and long.
- Table `Fence` contains (1) a column of type double representing a radius (2) and a foreign key reference to a Pin ID.

Given a lat, long and radius I would like to find any Pin+Fence that intersects (`ST_Intersects`) with the given circle.

Since I can't represent/save a circle in PostGIS as is and some answers on Stackoverflow refer to using ST_Buffer. Can I store the output of `ST_Buffer` or `ST_Envelope` in a new column in the `Fence` table and maybe use a trigger to update it (when Pin row get's updated)?

Comment: Please ask only one question per Question.

Comment: @Vince I edited the answer.

Comment: You seem to still be asking two questions.

Comment: @PolyGeo So you believe I should move the second part of my question (which is just a follow-up to the first part) to its own Question and then either repeat the same explanation of my use case or reference this question?. Is that better than what I did here?

Comment: If it is a follow up, then I think you should ask the first question, and *depending* on the answers, decide whether you need to ask the second separately.

Comment: @PolyGeo makes sense, I removed that part. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create another column:

```
SELECT *
FROM pins INNER JOIN fence ON pins.id=fence.point
WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_Buffer(pins.geom,fence.radius),ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(12 12)'), 10))
```

and you can store the output.  First create a new geometry column:

```
ALTER TABLE fence ADD COLUMN geom geometry
```

Then update the column:

```
UPDATE fence
SET geom=ST_Buffer(pins.geom,radius)
FROM pins
WHERE pins.id=fence.point
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but would I need the other column to store the bounding box and be able to use Spatial index, assuming I have thousands of locations (like it's mentioned here revenant.ca/www/postgis/workshop/indexing.html)?

Comment: @Jimmy Updated answer to include how to create a new column and then update the column based on info from the joined table.